# How do I loop through a list of columns in pg/PLSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table with about 3 dozen VARCHAR columns that all need the same cleanup before the record is inserted into the database (convert empty string to NULL). There are multiple apps accessing the DB, so I'd like to do this in a trigger. I could write code to check and set each column, but I'd like to loop through the columns instead. The function I wrote does not produce an error, but it also does not set empty columns to NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.validate_flds() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  coldata VARCHAR;
  collist VARCHAR[];
BEGIN
  collist := ARRAY[NEW.fld01,NEW.fld02,NEW.fld03];
  FOREACH coldata IN ARRAY collist LOOP
    IF coldata = '' THEN coldata := NULL; END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A loop with 36 statements every triggered on insert is going to harshly kill performance, especially if this table is hit by multiple apps.   Perhaps a better way of accomplishing your goals than a loop.

Comment: It's a low-volume system, so performance is not an issue.

Comment: You cannot to it in plpgsql. The record's fields cannot be accessed dynamically today - there is not necessary API. There are some workarounds, but none is good for update. Some years ago I wrote trigger function that does inverse transformation, but it can be easy modified https://github.com/okbob/replace_empty_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
IF coldata = '' THEN coldata := NULL; END IF;
```

you alter the value of the variable while the `NEW` record remains unchanged. There is no easy way to do what you want in a loop. I would suggest using [`NULLIF().`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF)

```
begin
    new.fld01:= nullif(new.fld01, '');
    new.fld02:= nullif(new.fld02, '');
    new.fld03:= nullif(new.fld03, '');
    return new;
end;
```